# How do you turn a cube into a sphere?

Tags: 3d, geometry, sphere

I'm trying to make a quad sphere based on [an article](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com.au/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html), which shows results like this:

[image: correct]

I can generate a cube correctly:

[image: before]

But when I convert all the points according to this formula (from the page linked above):

[image: formula]

```
    x = x * sqrtf(1.0 - (y*y/2.0) - (z*z/2.0) + (y*y*z*z/3.0));
    y = y * sqrtf(1.0 - (z*z/2.0) - (x*x/2.0) + (z*z*x*x/3.0));
    z = z * sqrtf(1.0 - (x*x/2.0) - (y*y/2.0) + (x*x*y*y/3.0));
```

My sphere looks like this:

[image: after]

As you can see, the edges of the cube still poke out too far. The cube ranges from `-1` to `+1` on all axes, like the article says.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Does your implementation contain "x = x ..." problem too or is it just here?

Comment: Fantastic visual aids. _Thankyou_ for including those.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you can just normalize the vertices of the cube to make it a sphere. The distribution of the vertices will probably be different from the linked method though.

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7189/morph-a-sphere-to-a-cube-and-a-cube-to-a-sphere-with-glsl

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You've miswritten the formula.

```
x = x * sqrtf(1.0 - (y*y/2.0) - (z*z/2.0) + (y*y*z*z/3.0));
y = y * sqrtf(1.0 - (z*z/2.0) - (x*x/2.0) + (z*z*x*x/3.0));
z = z * sqrtf(1.0 - (x*x/2.0) - (y*y/2.0) + (x*x*y*y/3.0));
```

You modify the original `x` and overwrite it. Then you modify `y` based not on the original `x` but the modified `x`. Then you modify `z` based on the modified version of *both* of those.

Preserve the originals, and calculate this:

```
float dx = x * sqrtf(1.0 - (y*y/2.0) - (z*z/2.0) + (y*y*z*z/3.0));
float dy = y * sqrtf(1.0 - (z*z/2.0) - (x*x/2.0) + (z*z*x*x/3.0));
float dz = z * sqrtf(1.0 - (x*x/2.0) - (y*y/2.0) + (x*x*y*y/3.0));
```

Use dx, dy and dz from then on.

Comment: Whoops. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: do u have any sample source for the above program?